# Ruby mathematic gem

Tags: ruby, math, geometry, linear-algebra

does anybody know if there is a good gem for mathematic / geometric operations? I need some of this things:

- Dot product
- Cross product
- Angle between vectors
- Matrix
- Surface normale
- Vector calculations (add, substract...)
- Singular Value Decomposition

thx,
tux

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I can highly recommend the [Ruby/GSL](http://rb-gsl.rubyforge.org/) gem.

You may need to refer to the [GSL manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/) to work out the name of the function you need to call though, if it's not documented in the Ruby/GSL documentation.

Comment: thx, I will try this out! and it's also available as a gem http://rubygems.org/gems/gsl

Comment: This wrapper looks really awesome!

Answer (score 2):

http://linalg.rubyforge.org/ seems to do what you want. It is based on LAPACK, the standard ultra tested 40-year linear algebra framework. Moreover, you can plug in vendor-specific LAPACK libraries for optimized code.

Comment: Hmmm, it seems that linalg is not available as a gem. Do you know a solution for it? I want to use it with bundler for a rails3 app.

Comment: @23tux: I never used ruby, I can't tell you. I know how to use Google however.

Comment: Don't waste your time with this. Pick Ruby/GSL gem instead.

Comment: I created a gem version, add

gem 'linalg', git: 'git://github.com/ivanku/linalg'

to your Gemfile

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this may help:
http://narray.rubyforge.org

Comment: Sorry, but I don't find any math calculations like I described above. How do you think to use narray for such calculations?

Comment: with GSL. They usualy go together.

Answer (score 0):

Linalg https://github.com/wedesoft ,  I posted instructions how to install it here: http://www.quora.com/Installation-Instructions/How-do-I-install-Ruby-linalg-library-on-Mac

Answer (score 0):

[NMatrix](http://github.com/SciRuby/nmatrix) from the SciRuby project might be what you're looking for.