# Ruby Library for doing Linear or NonLinear Least Squares Approximation?

Tags: ruby, linear-regression, least-squares

Is there a Ruby library that allows me to do either linear or non-linear least squares approximation of a set of data.

What I would like to do is the following:

- Given a series of [x,y] data points
- Generate a linear or non linear least squares approximation against that data
- The library doesn't have to figure out if it needs to do a linear or non linear approximation.  The caller of the library should know what type of regression they need

I'd prefer not to have to try to port some C/C++/Java library to get this functionality so I'm hoping there is some existing Ruby lib that I can use.

Comment: Did you try reading http://stackoverflow.com/questions/703717/anything-like-scipy-in-ruby and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5416655/ruby-mathematic-gem and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775013/scientific-programming-with-ruby ?

Comment: I did and I read through those libraries and only the linalg library implies that it can do least squares approx but when I dug through the source I couldn't find an implementation.

Comment: It might have been a good idea to mention that in your question.

Answer (score 8):

Try using the 'statsample' gem. You can perform logarithmic, exponential, power, or any other transformation using the example that is provided below. I hope this helps.

```
require 'statsample'

# Independent Variable
x_data = [Math.exp(1), Math.exp(2), Math.exp(3), Math.exp(4), Math.exp(5)]

# Dependent Variable
y_data = [3, 5, 7, 9, 11]

# Logarithmic Transformation of X data 
# Math.log in Ruby has the base of Euler's number 'e' ~= '2.71828', 
# instead of the base '10'. Just a note.
log_x_data = x_data.map { |x| Math.log(x) }

# Linear Regression using the Logarithmic Transformation
x_vector=log_x_data.to_vector(:scale)
y_vector=y_data.to_vector(:scale)
ds={'x'=>x_vector,'y'=>y_vector}.to_dataset
mlr=Statsample::Regression.multiple(ds,'y')
mlr.summary

# Provides the value of the y-intercept 
#p mlr.constant

# Lists the coefficients of each casual variable. In this case, we have only one--'x'.
#p mlr.coeffs

# The regression output produces the line y = 1 + 2*x, but 
# considering that we transformed x earlier, it really produces
# y = 1 + 2*ln(x).
```

Answer (score 7):

I used [this snippet](https://gist.github.com/990667) to work out some regressions. The first parameter is an array containing the x coordinates, the second an array containing the y coordinates and the last is the degree of the polynomial you are looking for. Not sure if it is this what you are looking for, but hopes it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I am maintaining a C library for non-linear least squares minimization, http://apps.jcns.fz-juelich.de/lmfit, that comes with swig files for Ruby.